# How to send a data from one page to another page with autofilling the form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a table in one page, and every row of this table has a button that redirects to another page with a form. I want the following: by pressing the button in the row of table, the data of this row goes to another page and fills the form by itself. And all i have to do is to submit

Comment: additional: i am a beginner and now know only python/django, html, css

Comment: Share the respective code , forms and models , then only other users will be able to sort out the solution

Comment: Show us your table and the form in another page that you want auto filled.

Comment: I hope you've heard about GET parameters. Your button can be an anchor which redirects to a url. This url will carry your row data. Example: `http://example.com/url-where-auto-fill-form-is/?name=myname&age=myAge`. In your django view you can easily do `request.GET.get('name')` `request.GET.get('age')` and send as context variables or however you want. Then simple use it in your template.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your question in it's current formulation cannot be properly answered, we need much more informations -  mostly the relevant model / views / template & js code ("relevant": edit out all that's not necessary for the example, cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).